# Why implement an immutable list as a linked-list?

Tags: f#

According to F#'s `list` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx):

- "*A list in F# is an ordered, **immutable** series of elements of the same type*"
- "*Lists in F# are implemented as **singly linked lists***"

Why not implement it contiguously in memory since it immutable and thus has a fixed size?  Why ever use an F# `list` instead of an F# `array`?

Comment: Related: [Why are cons lists associated with functional programming?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132309/why-are-cons-lists-associated-with-functional-programming)

Comment: One thing to consider is that the lists aren't actually fixed size - you write a lot of code that looks like `if something then a::(recurse ...) else []` here, building up the list with a linked list is natural

Comment: @JohnPalmer yes, they *are* fixed size. When you prepend an element, that creates a *new list*. The original list still exists, and has not changed in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They serve different purposes, for instance:

You use an Array in F# to store big amounts of data that needs to be accessed randomly with relative low overhead.

A List in F# is useful when you need to accumulate something over iterations of a recursive function. Arrays don't play well here, since they have a fixed size.

With a `list`, you can prepend all elements of ListM (size M) to ListN (size N) in O(M) time.  Similarly, you can prepend a single Element to any list in O(1) time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But I don't yet believe it :P.  In the case where a recursive method is concatenating `ListA` and `ListB`, it would point the tail of `ListA` to the head of `ListB`. But the idea that you can alter where the tail node of `ListA` is pointing would contradict that `ListA` is immutable.  That's my reasoning; please correct where I'm wrong.

Comment: The thing is that typically recursive methods don't concatenate, they append which is not the same. They append one element to the collection per iteration. Appending to a linked list is much cheaper than doing it to an array.

Comment: When you say "append", do you mean that it creates an entirely new list containing ListA and ListB?

Comment: No, append (or Cons) creates a new list containing ElementE and ListL. For example append 1 to [2;3;4] results in [1;2;3;4].

Comment: You may get confused because some functions in .NET and also in F# collections are called append and they do what you say, concatenate 2 lists. I think they are not named Concat because there is typically another one called Concat which concatenates a list of lists. Anyway I mean adding an element to the collection.

Comment: I think you've helped me understand it!  But I need to clarify: What you are describing is **pre**pending.  That would simply point `ElementE` to `ListL`.  That would have a runtime of O(1).  However **ap**pending would point `ListL` to `ElementE`, which would not be better, as it would have a runtime of O(L), *where L is the number of items in `ListL`*

Comment: Yes, it prepends an element to the list. Adding an element to the end of the list is not that cheap but typically you don't do that.